# Android Unit Testing for ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing

I have a question regarding Unit Testing. I am messing around with my application and I want to include unit testing to the development process. I use `ActionBarActivity`'s but the problemn is: where do I start? There are a lot of resources but I see different testing libraries, different ways of setting up the testing structure and for the 1,5 days that I have spent on learning and investigating the revenue is close to zero.

**Basically, my question**: Unit Testing on Android (with `ActionBarActivity`'s): where to start?

*Ps. I'm using Android Studio.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also found it same. It is damm difficult to get through unit test process for android.